# send image from server to client

Tags: c#, image

I want to send an image from the server to the client, so i did the following:

***in the server side :**

I convert the image to a byte array and then encrypt the array with md5 and send it to the client

and this is the code:

```
  byte[] byte1;

  Bitmap mg = new Bitmap(@"D:\ffffffffff13.jpg");
  Image im = mg;
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  im.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
  byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
  MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
  TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tDES = new
  TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
  tDES.Key = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("die"));
  tDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
  tDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
  ICryptoTransform trans = tDES.CreateEncryptor();
  byte1 = trans.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
  socket.BeginSend(byte1, 0, byte1.Length, SocketFlags.None, new
  AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
```

***in the client side :**

decrypte the byte array received from the server and then convert it to an image

and this is the code:

```
  byte[] receivedBuff = new byte[4000];
  int receiv = clientSocket.Receive(receivedBuff);
  byte[] data = new byte[receiv];
  Array.Copy(receivedBuff, data, receiv);

  MD5CryptoServiceProvider md51 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
  TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tDES1 = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
  tDES1.Key = md51.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("die"));
  tDES1.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
  tDES1.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
  ICryptoTransform trans1 = tDES1.CreateDecryptor();

  bytes2 = trans1.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
  MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(bytes2);
  Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms1);
  pictureBox2.Image = returnImage;
```

but when the client receives the byte array from the client an error occures in this ligne saing **Bad data**

```
  bytes2 = trans1.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
```

help please

Comment: This is a fairly frequently asked question. `Socket.Receive` returns the number of bytes read. You seem to assume that all the data will be read in one go. You should instead loop until `Receive` returns 0.

Comment: Daniel's comment should be promoted to "Answer." Also, MD5 is a hash (lossy), not an encryption scheme. You can't "encrypt the bytes" with MD5 and then convert them back to an image. What you've actually done here is encrypt the data using a key that you generated out of an MD5 hash (for whatever reasons) using the Triple-DES encryption algorithm.